# underfull \hbox (badness 1342) in paragraph

Tags: badness

This message of warning appears at the line 967, which says:

```
Las ecuaciones en \eqref{eq1.32} sugieren un m\'etodo para calcular las factorizaciones \QR reducidas. Dados $a^1,a^2,\dotsc$, podemos construir los vectores $\seq[q]{n}$ y los escalares $r_{ij}$ por un proceso de ortogonalizaci\'on sucesiva. Esta es una idea antigua, conocida como la \textit{ortogonalizaci\'on de Gram-Schimd}.
```

In the log file:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 1342) in paragraph at lines 967--968
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 Las ecua-ciones en [] su-gie-ren un m^^Setodo para cal-cu-lar las fac-to-ri-za-cio-nes
[]
```

Comment: that just means that TeX couldn't find a very good place to break the line and so that line is stretched more than specified. 1342 isn't _that_ bad though. Hard to say more without seeing the whole paragraph and language setuop.

Comment: You should say in your preamble `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` or words with accented characters will not be hyphenated. Probably "ortogonalización" is the culprit.

Comment: There's a good explanation from Overleaf to help you understand why it happens and how to solve it: https://pt.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Understanding_underfull_and_overfull_box_warnings

Answer (score 11):

Since you're writing in Spanish, which has many accented words, it's necessary to employ fonts in T1 encoding, that have glyphs for the accented characters. Otherwise TeX won't hyphenate words with accented letters past them.

Here's an example with your paragraph; I've made some suppositions about how the macros are defined.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,xspace}
\newcommand{\QR}{\textbf{QR}\xspace}
\newcommand{\seq}[2][x]{#1_1,#1_2,\dots,#1_{#2}}

\textwidth=.8\textwidth

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq1.32}
a=b
\end{equation}

Las ecuaciones en \eqref{eq1.32} sugieren un m\'etodo para calcular las 
factorizaciones \QR reducidas. Dados $a^1,a^2,\dotsc$, podemos construir 
los vectores $\seq[q]{n}$ y los escalares $r_{ij}$ por un proceso de
ortogonalizaci\'on sucesiva. Esta es una idea antigua, conocida como 
la \textit{ortogonalizaci\'on de Gram-Schimd}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If I remove the line `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, then I get the warning

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 1147) in paragraph at lines 16--21
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 Las ecua-cio-nes en [] su-gie-ren un
```

and the result is as follows (notice the bad spacing):

[image]

PS: It's "Gram-Schmidt"! I find it written in many different ways in my students' papers. :)

Comment: Thanks, good response, but I dont want use `fontenc` package, I solved my problem by changing the wording ... regards

Comment: @juanquispe You'll have several problems with hyphenation, if you don't use T1.

Comment: I'm carefull with wording :) ... is no major problem ... regards

Comment: I am only using English keywords and still get that error. The "\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}" didn't fix the issue. Any ideas?

Comment: @Alisa That happens; what value do you get?

Comment: @egreg I got "Underfull \hbox (badness 1859)", "Overfull \hbox (346.9 too wide)", "Overfull \vbox (4.7 too high)", etc., The first two are regarding \maketitle. 
PS: I am using WileyNJD-AMA.bst and WileyNJD-v2.cls.

Comment: @Alisa The underfull box is not so bad. The overfull by 346pt is definitely to be fixed. But it's a problem completely different from this question's.

Comment: Thanks @egreg for the comment.